# Customize woocommerce product name hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The reason behind doing this is because I am currently had set my default product name hook with a custom function and I am currently trying to set another custom hook to avoid conflict with my default hook. This is what I have here for my custom function(hook). Please feel free to give suggestions on the custom function that I created. (Which is not working at the moment)

The code is below:

```
add_action('custome_product_name', 'show_product_name');

function show_product_name(){
    $product = wc_get_product(id);
    echo $product->get_title();
}
```

Feel free to ask if there is any confusion that I caused. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Above one is for (WC version 2.5.2) can let me know which version of WC you are using ?

Can try below action hook please:

```
add_action('custome_product_name', 'show_product_name');
function show_product_name(){
    echo get_the_title( 'ID' );
}
```

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks for the fast reply. The version I'm currently using is 3.8.1. Cheers.

Comment: global $product;  echo $product->get_name();  check as well as